# Changing hover image after repeated hovers using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I am trying to change the src attribute in an img tag in html using jquery, I want scr attribute to change differently depending on the number of times the user has hovered over the img element.

My html is set up as follows:

```
<img id="element" src="img1.png">
```

My js/jQuery is set up as follows:

```
var count = 0;

if(count == 0){
        $("#element").hover(function(){
            count++;
            $("#element").attr("src","img2.png");
        }, function(){
            $("#element").attr("src","img1.png");
        });
} else if(count>=1){
        $("#element").hover(function(){
            count++;
            $("#element").attr("src","img3.png");
        }, function(){
            $("#element").attr("src","img1.png");
        });
}
```

The hover function on its own works fine, and hovering in and out will switch between two images.  However, my goal is to make it switch to img2 in the first hover, and then img3 at the second hover, and thereafter.  My hover function seems to work fine if I want it to hover between img1 and img2 or img 1 and img3, that is when I remove if statement and count variable.

If someone could help identify my problem please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the counter check within the hover handler

```js
var counter = 0;
$("#element").hover(function() {
  $(this).attr("src", ++counter > 1 ? '//placehold.it/64X64/00ff00' : '//placehold.it/64X64/0000ff');
}, function() {
  $(this).attr("src", "//placehold.it/64X64/ff0000");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="element" src="//placehold.it/64X64/ff0000">
```

In your code the value of `counter` is checked only once on page load where the value of counter is always 0

Comment: I tried adding this counter check, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Very nice!!  This worked.  Can you explain to me what: ++counter > 1 ? '//placehold.it/64X64/00ff00' : '//placehold.it/64X64/0000ff' part of the function does exactly?  I am unfamiliar with the ? and : notation occurring here

Comment: I would like to generalize this to more than just 3 images in total, but I should be able to take it from here once I know exactly what that part does

Comment: @user3859248 that is the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: it is like if the condition `++counter > 1` is true then return `//placehold.it/64X64/00ff00` else `//placehold.it/64X64/0000ff` - like a `if...else` statement

Comment: Thank you, seems like they can be nested, however hover seems to be going a little wild when you mouse hovers over the elements too long

Comment: @user3859248 sorry what do you mean by the second point... for the first point there can be better solutions if you can give the use case.... nesting the ternary operator is not a good idea in terms of usability

Comment: So, I am trying to nest them in so far that I want the picture to change for every time you hover.  So at x=1 display img1, at x=2 display img 2, at x=3 display img3, at x=4 display img4, at x=>5 display img5.  What seems to be happening is that it is counting up too fast, ie I think I am hovering over the element but while I am hovering over the element it is changing picture several times, before I leave the element

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, `if(count == 0)` occurs in your setup code. None of your hover event handlers touch the value of `count`, so once the handlers are set (either to 1 and 2 or 1 and 3), they will never be changed. And since count is always zero when the handlers are added, you always get the first pair.

Instead, you should switch between the two images inside of your handler function, not in the code that assigns the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating array of strings containing `img` `src` , utilizing `Array.prototype.reverse()` to toggle images

```
    var imgs = ["img2.png", "img3.png"];
    $("#element").hover(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", imgs[0]);
      imgs.reverse()
    }, function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "img1.png");
    });
```

```js
    var imgs = ["http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats"];
    $("#element").hover(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", imgs[0]);
      imgs.reverse()
    }, function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="element" width="100px" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature" />
```

Comment: how would I generalize this to n variables in the array, and not just two?

Answer (score 0):

What about some simplicity?

```
var counter = 1;
$("#element").hover(function () {
    counter = (counter===3) ? 1 : (counter+1);
    $(this).attr("src", 'img'+counter+'.png');
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens here:

Comment: counter = (counter===3) ? 1 : (counter+1);

Comment: If the counter equal to 3, then it will be reset to 1, otherwise it will just increase by one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work just something I looked up but you can try it.
Just add more variables to it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

//rollover swap images with rel

var img_src = "";
var new_src = "";

$(".rollover").hover(function(){
 //mouseover

img_src = $(this).attr('src'); //grab original image

new_src = $(this).attr('rel'); //grab rollover image

$(this).attr('src', new_src); //swap images

$(this).attr('rel', img_src); //swap images

},
function(){
//mouse out

$(this).attr('src', img_src); //swap images

$(this).attr('rel', new_src); //swap images
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 1;

    $("#element").hover(function() {

        count++;
       $(this).attr("src","img"+count+".png");

       if(count == 3){
        //Reset the count
        count = 0;
       }

    }, function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "img1.png");

    });
});
```